# Puppet agent not updating catalog changes

Tags: puppet

I'm using

```
Puppet Master version 2.7.25
Puppet Agent version 2.7.25
```

Successfully signed the certificate for puppet agent.

After that created a new class as below:

```
class hosts {
    file { "/tmp/hosts"
            owner => root,
            group => root,
            mode => 755,
     }
}
```

Updated nodes.pp file with the above module.

Running puppet module list on master gave:

```
/etc/puppet/modules
âââ hosts (???)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

When i run puppet agent --test it says:

```
info: Caching catalog for dev104.nbec.in
info: Applying configuration version '1391609901'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
```

But i don't see any file named hosts created under /tmp folder.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it was my mistake of `site.pp` named as `sites.pp`.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing host class ***declaration***, but it seems that you don't ***instantiate*** it. You will need an `include host` or `require host` somewhere into your `node`dev104.nbec.in or your `node default` declaration